# WordPress 404 page not working on Windows Phone

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, windows-phone-8

I have a really weird issue with my WordPress installation and Windows Phone. The WordPress files are in a subdirectory and I use .htaccess to get there (just for my IP):

```
# HOME
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^###\.###\.###\.###$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www.)?([a-z0-9_\-]+).)?alleenf1.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-alleenf1/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-alleenf1/$1 [L]
```

This works perfectly on my computer and on an Android phone / tablet. But when I get to my Windows Phone (WP8), I cannot access my 404 error page. Every other page in WordPress works, except the 404 page. I get a default "page not found". Really weird.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you need to clear cache on your phone?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work :-(. Tnx